# How to overwrite a warning in R

Tags: r, error-handling, rlang

I have a function that generates an unwanted warning, but keeps the value.

```r
f <- function(a) { 
  
  if (a > 1) { 
    warning("an uninformative warning")
  }
  a
}

g1 <- function(b) {
  
  withCallingHandlers(
    x <-f(b),
    warning = function(w) {
      warning("A more informative warning")
    })
  
  x
}
g1(2)
#> Warning in (function (w) : A more informative warning
#> Warning in f(b): an uninformative warning
#> [1] 2
```

<sup>Created on 2023-12-12 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Unfortunately, this thows 2 warnings.

With `tryCatch()` x is not kept. and with `withCallingHandlers()`, both warnings are thrown.

Comment: `try(..., silent = TRUE)` is worth a go.

Comment: @PGSA `try()` is generally discouraged and doesn’t help here; but `tryCatch()` might (but I don’t think so).

Comment: tryCatch() doesn't keep `x` unfortunately.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can get your `warning` handler to emit its own warning, then invoke the `muffleWarning` restart:

```r
f <- function(a) { 
  
  if (a > 1) { 
    warning("an uninformative warning")
  }
  a
}

g1 <- function(b) {
  
  withCallingHandlers(
    x <- f(b),
    warning = function(w) {
      warning('A more informative warning', call. = FALSE)
      tryInvokeRestart("muffleWarning")
    })
  x
}
```

Testing:

```r
g1(2)
#> [1] 2
#> Warning message:
#> A more informative warning
```

Comment: Seems like it works, never saw `tryInvokeRestart("muffleWarning")`, will investigate!

Comment: Okay, can you explain *why* this works? Why is the restart only swallowing the first warning, but not the second one?

Comment: @KonradRudolph why _would_ it swallow the second warning? The second warning is signalled by the condition handler before the restart is invoked. The restart does not evaluate or execute any code within the condition handler.

Comment: “The second warning is signalled by the condition handler before the restart is invoked.” — exactly: R has now registered two warnings, which are stored in `base::last.warning`. In my mental model, the `muffleWarning` restart empties this list. Clearly this is not correct, but I can’t find any information about what the restart *actually* does. (Actually I am aware that the restart does no such thing … in fact, *it simply does nothing*. But then, how is `base::last.warning` modified?)

Comment: Okay, I *think* what happens is that `.signalCondition()` will trigger the calling handler which then invokes the restart, whereas `.dfltWarn()` writes the warning object to `base::last.warning`. And that call is never reached when we muffle the warning, so the first warning never gets written into `base::last.warning` in the first place.

Comment: Another question: do we *need* to use `tryInvokeRestart()` here? At the point where we’re in the `warning` calling handler we *know* that the restart was set up, don’t we? So `invokRestart()` should always work.

Comment: @KonradRudolph yes, I think that's right.  `base::last.warning` is not written to if a warning is encountered inside the code evaluated inside `withCallingHandlers` (if you print the last warning from inside the warning handler, the "caught" warning isn't there). The warning handler is invoked for each individual warning condition encountered in place of the normal warning signalling. It does not silence all warnings. My mental model is that `tryInvokeRestart("muffleWarning")` means "do nothing further with the warning and run the rest of the expression"

Comment: @KonradRudolph I'm sure `invokeRestart` is fine. If something weird happened and somehow the muffleWarning restart wasn't available it would halt execution, which would probably be a good thing. I think the documentation for condition handling in R  is very sparse, and the implementation has relatively little high-level abstraction. Tracking what's going on in the C code requires either a lot of cross-referencing, or achieving a higher level of familiarity with the R internals than that to which I have thus far treated myself.